# sed: flexible template w/ line number constraint

Tags: bash, templates, sed

**Problem**
I need to insert text of arbitrary length ( # of lines ) into a template while maintaining an exact number of total lines.

Sample source data file:

```
You have a hold available for pickup as of 2012-01-13:
Title: Really Long Test Title Regarding Random Gibberish. Volume 1, A-B, United States
 and affiliated territories, United Nations, countries of the world
Author: Barrel Roll Morton
Title: How to Compromise Free Speech Using Everyday Tools. Volume XXVI
Author: Lamar Smith
#end-of-record
You have a hold available for pickup as of 2012-01-13:
Title: Selling Out Democracy For Fun and Profit. Volume 1, A-B, United States
Author: Lamar Smith
Copy: 12
#end-of-record
```

Sample Template ( simplified for brevity ):

```
<%CUST-NAME%>
<%CUST-ADDR%>
<%CUST-CTY-ZIP%>

<%TITLES GO HERE%>

<%STORE-NAME%>
<%STORE-ADDR%>
<%STORE-CTY-ZIP%>
```

At this point I use bash's 'mapfile' to load the source file
record by record using the /^#end-of-file/ regex ...so far so good.
Then I pull predictable aspects of each record according to the line
on which they occur, then process the info using a series of sed 
search replace statements.

**The Hang-Up**
So the problem is the unknown number of 'title' records that could occur. 
How can I accommodate an unknown number of titles and always have output 
of precisely 65 lines?

Given that title records always occur starting on line 8, I can pull the 
titles easily with:

```
 sed -n '8,$p' test-match.txt
```

However, how can I insert this within an allotted space, ex, between <%CUST-CTY-ZIP%> and <%STORE-NAME%> without pushing the store info out of place in the template?

My idea so far:

-first send the customer info through:
  
Ex.

```
sed 's/<%CUST-NAME%>/Benedict Arnold/' template.txt
```

-Append title records
  ???

-Then the store/location info

```
sed 's/<%STORE-NAME%>/Smith's House of Greasy Palms/' template.txt
```

I have code and functions for this stuff if interested but this post is 'windy' as it is.
Just need help with inserting the title records while maintaining position of following text and maintaining total line number of 65.*

**UPDATE**
I've decided to change tactics. I'm going to create place holders in the template for all available lines between customer and store info --- then:

- Test if line is null in source
- if yes -- replace placeholder with null leaving the line ending. Line number maintained.
- if not null -- again, replace with text, maintaining line number and line endings in template.

Eventually, I plan to invest some time looking closer at Triplee's suggestion regarding Perl. The Perl way really does look simpler and easier to maintain if I'm going to be stuck with this project long term.

Comment: Are you asking about padding or squeezing? If stuff needs to be squeezed, what are we allowed to delete? If padding, where should the padding go? `sed` is not very good with arithmetic, but with awk it would be trivial to add newlines at the end until output is 65 lines.

Comment: could be either. If only one title than padding ...if 5 or more, some will have to be cut.

Comment: The stuff under the arbitrary number of title entries has to occur on the exact same lines ...so there'd have to be a way to count lines, then either squeeze or pad to allow footer to happen predictably ...with a tasteful newline for easy viewing

Comment: So %STORE-NAME should land on something like line 62 regardless of how many titles there are? Sounds like a job for Perl's formats, no need IMHO to go to Template Toolkit if you can get it right with `s2p` plus some minor refactoring.

Comment: Have a look at the `eval()` suggestion at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
cat <<! >titles.txt
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> 6
> 7
> Title 1
> Title 2   
> Title 3
> Title 4
> Title 5
> Title 6
> !
cat <<! >template.txt
> <%CUST-NAME%>
> <%CUST-ADDR%>
> <%CUST-CTY-ZIP%>
> 
> <%TITLES GO HERE%>
> 
> <%STORE-NAME%>
> <%STORE-ADDR%>
> <%STORE-CTY-ZIP%>
> !
sed '1,7d;:a;$!{N;ba};:b;G;s/\n[^\n]*//5g;tc;bb;:c;s/\n/\\n/g;s|.*|/<%TITLES GO HERE%>/c\\&|' titles.txt | 
sed -f - template.txt
<%CUST-NAME%>
<%CUST-ADDR%>
<%CUST-CTY-ZIP%>

Title 1
Title 2
Title 3
Title 4
Title 5

<%STORE-NAME%>
<%STORE-ADDR%>
<%STORE-CTY-ZIP%>
```

This pads/squeezes the titles to 5 lines (`s/\n[^\n]*//5g`) if you want fewer or more change the `5` to the number desired.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you five lines of output regardless of the number of lines in `titles.txt`:

```
sed -n '$s/$/\n\n\n\n\n/;8,$p' test-match.txt | head -n 5
```

Another version:

```
sed -n '8,$N; ${s/$/\n\n\n\n\n/;s/\(\([^\n]*\n\)\{4\}\).*/\1/p}' test-match.txt
```

Use one less than the number of lines you want (4 in this example will cause 5 lines of output).

Comment: The question states: `Given that title records always occur starting on line 8`

Comment: @potong: My `cat` was more or less a placeholder. I've updated my question to use the `sed` command from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick proof of concept using Perl formats.  If you are unfamiliar with Perl, I guess you will need some additional help with how to get the values from two different files, but it's quite doable, of course.  Here, the data is simply embedded into the script itself.

I set the `$titles` format to 5 lines instead of the proper value (58 or something?) in order to make this easier to try out in a terminal window, and to demonstrate that the output is indeed truncated when it is longer than the allocated space.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                 

use strict;
use warnings;

use vars (qw($cust_name $cust_addr $cust_cty_zip $titles                        
    $store_name $store_addr $store_cty_zip));

my $fmtline = '@' . '<' x 78;
my $titlefmtline = '^' . '<' x 78;
my $empty = '';
my $fmt = join ("\n$fmtline\n", 'format STDOUT = ',
                '$cust_name', '$cust_addr', '$cust_cty_zip', '$empty') .
    ("\n$titlefmtline\n" . '$titles') x 5 . #58                                 
    join ("\n$fmtline\n", '', '$empty',
          '$store_name', '$store_addr', '$store_cty_zip');
#print $fmt;                                                                    
eval "$fmt\n.\n";

titles = <<____HERE;
Title: Really Long Test Title Regarding Random Gibberish. Volume 1, A-B, United States
 and affiliated territories, United Nations, countries of the world
Author: Barrel Roll Morton
Title: How to Compromise Free Speech Using Everyday Tools. Volume XXVI
Author: Lamar Smith
____HERE
# Preserve line breaks -- ^<< will fill lines, but preserves line breaks on \r  
$titles =~ s/\n/\r\n/g;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    ($cust_name, $cust_addr, $cust_cty_zip, $store_name, $store_addr, $store_cty_zip)
        = split (",");
    write STDOUT;
}
__END__
Charlie Bravo,23 Alpa St,Delta ND 12345,Spamazon,98 Spamway,Atlanta GA 98765
```

The use of `$empty` to get an empty line is pretty ugly, but I wanted to keep the format as regular as possible.  I'm sure it could be avoided, but at the cost of additional code complexity IMHO.

If you are unfamiliar with Perl, the `use strict` is a complication, but a practical necessity; it requires you to declare your variables either with `use vars` or `my`.  It is a best practice which helps immensely if you try to make changes to the script.

Here documents with `<<HERE` work like in shell scripts; it allows you to create a multi-line string easily.

The `x` operator is for repetition; `'string' x 3` is `'stringstringstring'` and `("list") x 3` is `("list" "list" "list")`.  The dot operator is string concatenation; that is, `"foo" . "bar"` is `"foobar"`.

Finally, the `DATA` filehandle allows you to put arbitrary data in the script file itself after the `__END__` token which signals the end of the program code.  For reading from standard input, use `<>` instead of `<DATA>`.

Comment: Familiar with perl, but rusty. I'll take a look at this and give it a shot.Thanks!